# Import Javascript files as a string?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to be able to simply do an `import file from 'file.js` and then have file be a string of the contents within file.js. I've toyed around with raw-loader but it doesn't give me the same contents (instead it loads it in a different format). Any suggestions?

Comment: Raw loader is the way to go. Maybe you are using Babel as well and it's applied *before* raw loader does its thing? Can you sure your code and configuration?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the reply. How would I go about checking/changing things if that is the case? edit: figured it out, just needed to change `raw-loader` to `!raw-loader`

Comment: Applying the loader with `import file from '!raw-loader!file.js'` might do the trick. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#via-require

Comment: exactly, thank you!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> it doesn't give me the same contents (instead it loads it in a different format)

That seems to mean that there are other loaders from your config applied to the file. You can enforce that only the loader in the import statement is used by prefixing it with a `!`:

```
import file from '!raw-loader!file.js'
```

From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#via-require):

> It's possible to overwrite any loaders in the configuration by prefixing the entire rule with `!`.

Answer (score 3):

In Webpack 5 it's possible to handle it without raw-loader.
It's enough to add a rule with `type: asset/source` (see the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)). Note that in this case, if you use babel loader or other JS loaders, the code will still be processed by them if not overridden manually.

A simplified code example:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /(?<!boilerplate)\.js$/, // a negative look-behind regex to exclude your file
      exclude: /node_modules/, // also can be handled here, adding a folder with file(s) to be excluded
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /boilerplate\.js$/,
      type: 'asset/source'
    },
  ]
}
```