# Symfony Webpack-Encore minify Js and CSS

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I want minify all css and js of my project in symfony.
in Symfony 3 I use Assetic for JS like this as simple:

```
{% javascripts
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
    '@AcmeBarBundle/Resources/public/js/form.js'
    '@AcmeBarBundle/Resources/public/js/calendar.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

and for CSS same.
But in symfony 4 recommended to use Webpack Encore but i have a few problems:

1. The Webpack downloads all the dependencies while I have the JavaScript files of them And I do not want to download.
2. Sometimes it does not have some libraries that occur failed to download. but I have a JS file of library and I do not want to download.

Now I just want to minify my JavaScript files without interference like Assetic. (like check and download dependency, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Webpack Encore is simply wrapper around Webpack. So you can use [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/). For example via [inline configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031020/13962131).