# How to post router views to backend once after each build

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I have a Vue with typescript project and in the `routes.ts` file all the routes are defined. What I've been trying to do is to post all the routes contained here to a backend endpoint, this should be done once after each new build.

Ideally, I should be able to import the routes file into the file that serves the app, this option isn't working right now as many dependencies are broken since the server file uses its own independent `tsconfig` file and it seems that it's unable to resolve the lazy imports.

A typical route in my application looks like this:

```
{ 
 path: 'editar-cliente/:clientId',
  name: 'EditClientInformation',
  meta: {
    alias: 'Editar información',
  },
  component: () => import('@/views/v2/clients-management/EditClientInformation.vue'),
};
```

I need all the information from every object with this structure except for the `component` key.

Is there a way in which I could achieve this?

Comment: What you can do is for each route, do `delete item.component;`

Comment: @LeandroMatilla Already tried it, I created a deep copy of the object and then deleted the `component` section, but as it is in the same file where the actual import property is the imports keep breaking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029866/import-javascript-files-as-a-string